# How Do API calls for Login License per user get calculated for customer community?

Tags: customer-community

As we calculate login license user, For instance, if you purchased 20K logins, you can use 20K logins every month.
Is the same calculation goes for API calls for Login License per user ?
As per login license calculation, API calls calculation is also cumulative?

Answer (score 1):

> For instance, if you purchased 20K logins, you can use 20K logins every month

Based on the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&type=5), the login type licenses are actually provisioned in 1:20 ratio. So in this case you will actually have 400,000 licenses.

> The ration between the number of monthly logins you purchase and the number of login licenses that are provisioned in your org is 1 to 20. For example, if you purchase 1,000 monthly logins, then 20,000 login licenses are provisioned in your org.

In the same documentation, you will find the limits for API Only calls mentioned as in the screenshot below. Unfortunately, it looks like for Customer Community, there's none available and only available for other Community license types.

[image]